# MySQL update query without join

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I want to correct comments in a table by checking the value against a list in another table. Like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_substitution, tbl_comments
SET tbl_comments.comment = replace(tbl_comments.comment,tbl_substitution.word,tbl_substitution.word_replace);
```

Although this works alright in MS Access, I notice with MySQL that only the first value of the substitution table is used. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Which column(s) define the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: No join was made deliberately, in order to check each comment against each substitution value.

Comment: You can't use this approach.  What is happening is that each replacement _is_ happening, but only the final replacement is actually "sticking".

Comment: In fact, only the first substitution is applied. Unlike with MS Access, as I mentioned.